# How to scale proportionally?

Tags: edit-mode

I need to scale an object like at the right (in attached Pic) linearly, when bottom will remain the same, and top will be scaled. With cube its easy to do, but object at the right retrieves edges out with total broken geometry.

I already tried to parent object to the cube and scale like at the left, but have no effect.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proportional editing is available via the "O" shortcut, or through the menu button as below. The mouse wheel controls the area being influenced (circle indicator in 3rd picture).

[[image]

[image]

[image]